# Returning multiple types

Tags: c++, feedback

The following code snippet is of a game, the compiler is complaining about the return values so I would like some feedback on how to otherwise do this trick to let a function return two different types based on the type put in but without overloading

```
template <typename T>
T GetTimeDead(uint64 Guid)
{
    bool stringOutput;
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(float))
        stringOutput = false;
    else
        stringOutput = true;

    bool found = false;
    for(map<uint32, TrackInfo>::iterator itr = dieTracker.begin(); itr != dieTracker.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(itr->second.GUID == Guid)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        stringOutput ? return "never" : return sObjectMgr->FindCreature(Guid)->GetCreatureData()->spawntimesecs;

    if(!stringOutput)
        return dieTracker.find(Guid)->second.seconds;
    float seconds = dieTracker.find(Guid)->second.seconds;
    uint64 secs    = seconds % 60;
    uint64 minutes = seconds % 3600 / 60;
    uint64 hours   = seconds % 86400  / 3600;
    uint64 days    = seconds / 86400;
    ostringstream ss;
    if(days)
        days != 1 ? ss << days << " Days " : ss << days << " Day ";
    if(hours)
        hours != 1 ? ss << hours << " Hours" : ss << hours << " Hour";
    if(minutes)
        minutes != 1 ? ss << minutes << " Minutes " : ss << minutes << " Minutes ";
    if(secs || (!days && !hours && !minutes))
        secs != 1 ? ss << secs << " Seconds " : ss << secs << " Second ";
    ss << "ago";
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: error C2059: syntax error : 'return'

Comment: it sounds like the compiler is right: you are trying to do a Bad Thing. Can you add an explanation what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: You simply can't have a function that returns two different types depending on what happens inside the function.

Comment: This is not possible because the compiler has to create a function for each type T but since it's the return type and therefore not included in the function signature, both functions will have the same signature and can't exist at the same time.

Comment: That's what I was trying to accomplish, returning a different type according to the input.

Comment: You *could* return a pair of `std::string` and `T` and make the user check whether the string is empty for `T` being valid. That doesn't seem like a solution, though.

Comment: user2373581, you don't even try to return different type according to the input here, unless by "input" you mean "template argument". If that was your question, @user2093113 aswered it. But it is very unlikely you actually need something like that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to define generic behaviour with a template, but override that behaviour for a handful of specific types, you should use a **template specialisation**.

```
template<typename T>
std::string GetTimeDead(uint64 Guid)
{ /* code to implement your version that returns std::string */
}

template<>
float GetTimeDead<float>(uint64 Guid)
{ /* code to implement your version that returns float */
}
```

The reason for your error at the moment is that you have defined the return type to be `T`. But your logic is set up so that if `T` is of type `float` the function tries to return a `std::string`. There is likely no implicit cast from `std::string` to `T`, hence the error.

If you don't want to repeat common code, you could pull that out into a separate template function which is called by the two above.

Comment: Your answer is good if you actually need a template. It doesn't seem like this is the case here, to me.

Comment: I agree to Elazar. The template parameter is only used to determine if a string or a float is returned. However IF you still for some reason need a template... your snipped was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a strong and statically typed compiled language - you cannot have a function that returns different types. You are limited to a single return type.

That being said, you can use Boost's `variant` or Qt's `QVariant`, which can encapsulate different types. Or implement a custom variant solution tailored to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error `error C2059: syntax error : 'return'`, this is the way to fix this *specific* error:

```
return stringOutput ? "never" : sObjectMgr->FindCreature(Guid)->GetCreatureData()->spawntimesecs;
```

the `?:` operator is an expression, and each argument of the operator should be an expression. `return` is a *statement*. not an expression.

As an expression, `?:` has exactly single type. but `"never"` and `spawntimesecs` are unrelated types. The compiler cannot handle that. these two values does not belong in the same `?:` expression.

You can probably use a union, but it is not recommended.

A better solution will not use template at all, since you do not use the type parameter in any polymorphic way:

```
float GetTimeDeadFloat(uint64 Guid)
{
    return find(Guid)
           ? dieTracker.find(Guid)->second.seconds
           : sObjectMgr->FindCreature(Guid)->GetCreatureData()->spawntimesecs;
}

string GetTimeDeadString(uint64 Guid)
{
    return find(Guid)
           ? timeToString(dieTracker.find(Guid)->second.seconds)
           : "never";
}


bool find(uint64 Guid) {
    for(map<uint32, TrackInfo>::iterator itr = dieTracker.begin(); itr != dieTracker.end(); ++itr) {
        if(itr->second.GUID == Guid)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

string timeToString(float seconds) {
    string res = timeToString(seconds % 3600 / 60, "Minutes");
    res += timeToString(seconds % 86400  / 3600, "Hour");
    res += timeToString(seconds / 86400, "Day");
    if (secs || res.length() == 0)
        res += numToString(seconds % 60, "Second");
    res += "ago";
    return res;
}


string numToString(uint64 num, string type) {
    ostringstream ss;
    if (num)
        ss << num << " " << type << (num != 1) ? "s" : "" << " ";
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: but it is a *runtime* check. so it cannot affect the compile time types.